# Jquery UI sortable detects axis up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I am struggling to detect if axis N is moving up or down? and also i want the objects (h2 and p) inside, stay on the position. Can someone help please!

http://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/y62awe4u/2/

```
<div class="ss-zone-object" style="top: 68px; width:300px; height: 500px; left: 20px;">
    <h2 style="top: 100px; width: 60px;">Title</h2>
    <p style="left: 122px; top: 120px; width: 60px;">Summary</p>
</div>

 $(function () {
    $('.ss-zone-object').resizable({
        grid: [1, 1],
        handles: 'n,s',
        resize: function (e, ui) {
            var handle_axis = $(this).data('ui-resizable').axis;

            $(this).find('h2, p').each(function (mk, mv) {

                var obj_top = parseInt($(this).position().top);
                if (handle_axis === 'n') { // Axis N, moving down then minus one
                    $(this).css('top', (obj_top - 1) + 'px');
                } else if (handle_axis === 's') {

                }
            });

        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: _"Jquery UI **sortable** detects axis up and down"_ ?, `$('.ss-zone-object').resizable({` ?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/  read this it might be helpful..

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? What is axis N? Do you mean that the objects inside the div needs to stay fixed when you scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to do it by adding temporary clone div.

http://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/y62awe4u/9/

```
$('.ss-zone-clone').resizable({
        grid: [1, 1],
        handles: 'n,s',
        containtment: 'parent',
        start: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).css({
                'background': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                    'z-index': 1
            });
        },
        resize: function (e, ui) {
            var handle_axis = $(this).data('ui-resizable').axis;
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).css({
                'background': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                    'z-index': 0
            });

            var h2_top = $('.ss-zone-object').find('h2').position().top;

            var orig_top = ui.originalPosition.top;
            var cur_top = ui.position.top;
            var new_top;

            new_top = (cur_top - orig_top);

            $('.ss-zone-object').css({
                'height': ui.size.height + 'px',
                    'top': cur_top + 'px'
            });

            $('.ss-zone-object').find('h2').css('top', (h2_top - new_top));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Oke i have for example, this is:

```js
$(function () {
    var s = $('h2').position().top;
    var p = $('h2').position().top;
    var height_font_s = 68; // define manual
    var height_font_p = 88; // define manual
    $('.ss-zone-object').resizable({
        grid: [1, 1],
        handles: 'n,s',
        resize: function (e, ui) {
            var handle_axis = $(this).data('ui-resizable').axis;
            var t = $('.ss-zone-object').position().top;
            $(this).find('h2').css('top', (-(t-(s+height_font_s)))+'px');
            $(this).find('p').css('top', (-(t-(p+height_font_p)))+'px');
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {}
    });

})
```

```css
.ss-zone-object {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position:absolute;
}
.ss-zone-object h2, .ss-zone-object p {
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="ss-zone-object" style="top: 68px; width:300px; height: 500px; left: 20px;">
     <h2 style="top: 100px; width: 60px;">Title</h2>

    <p style="left: 122px; top: 120px; width: 60px;">Summary</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve in here.

> I am struggling to detect if axis N is moving up or down?

If you want to detect the Axis (N or S) you just can check within the resize event handler the following:

```
var handle_axis = ui.originalPosition.top === ui.position.top ? "s" : "n";
```

> and also i want the objects (h2 and p) inside, stay on the position.

When resizing the South axis, there's no problem, as the elements are position to the top of the contianer.

When resizing the North axis, the two element's top positon never changes in relation to the parent. However, you can use ui.originalSize and ui.size to find out what's the new top position. OR just set position fixed.